# cakephp - sql injection test always shows failure

Tags: sql, cakephp, code-injection

I have project developed using cakephp 1.3 and for testing I used [SQL Inject me addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7597/) (firefox)

From [cakephp manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/153/Data-Sanitization), what I understood is, the save() and find() methods will automatically protect the data from SQL injection. But while running "SQL inject me" test, I am always getting failures as result.

For ex: Results:
Server Status Code: 302 Found
Tested value: 1' AND 1=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablenames); --
Server Status Code: 302 Found
Tested value: '; DESC users; --
Server Status Code: 302 Found
Tested value: 1'1

I have tried with cakephp santize methods, then also I am getting the errors in "sql inject me".

Any help ?

Sample code

```
$this->data['User'] = Sanitize::clean($this->data['User'], array('encode' => false));
$this->User->save($this->data);
```

Comment: Yes, those methods do prevent SQL injection. Could you show us some code?

Comment: No need to add sanitize like that, find() will do it for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[How to fix Server Status Code: 302 Found by SQL Inject Me Firefox Addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283476/how-to-fix-server-status-code-302-found-by-sql-inject-me-firefox-addon)

that error shows that the sql injection has been prevented. You don't need Sanitize for SQL injection, but for XSS.

Comment: and not even there sanitize is needed. a simple h() does the trick as well.

Comment: But it is showing as failure. Is there any way to find out the error codes and description. Screen shots http://www.2shared.com/photo/4vu4n-iJ/Results1.html
http://www.2shared.com/photo/hPKKrceK/Results2.html

Comment: the 9 failures shown there, I believe, is because Cake reacts differently than the addon expects. In the controller, you are redirecting to another page, right? Like the answer in the link I posted, it is a perfectly normal server response. You might want to send your result to the addon's author.